# How do I take a conjugate transpose?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, fermions, dirac-equation

In Klauber's "Student Friendly QFT" second edition page 463, the following expression for $M$ is given in equation 17-98:
$$M = \left( \bar{u}_{s'_2}(p_2') \gamma_\alpha v_{s'_1}(p_1')\right)_{(l)} \frac{i e^2}{\left(p_1 + p_2\right)^2} \left(\bar{v}_{s_1}(p_1) \gamma^\alpha u_{s_2} (p_2)\right)_{(e)}$$
where subscript $e$ stands for electron and $l$ for $\mu$ or $\tau$.

Then in equation 17-100:
$$M^* = \left(\bar{v}'_{s'_1}\gamma_\beta u_{s'_2}(p_2')\right)_{(l)} \frac{-i e^2}{\left(p_1 + p_2\right)^2} \left(\bar{u}_{s_2} (p_2) \gamma^\beta v_{s_1} (p_1) \right)_{(e)}$$

This seems to be saying $(ABC)^* = A^* B^* C^*$, where:
$$A^* = \left(\bar{v}'_{s'_1}\gamma_\beta u_{s'_2}(p_2')\right)_{(l)}$$
$$B^* = \frac{-i e^2}{\left(p_1 + p_2\right)^2}$$
$$C^* = \left(\bar{u}_{s_2} (p_2) \gamma^\beta v_{s_1} (p_1) \right)_{(e)}$$

Why isn't it the following (because $(ABC)^* = C^* B^* A^*$):
$$\left(\bar{u}_{s_2} (p_2) \gamma^\beta v_{s_1} (p_1) \right)_{(e)} \frac{-i e^2}{\left(p_1 + p_2\right)^2} \left(\bar{v}'_{s'_1} \gamma_\beta u_{s'_2}(p_2')\right)_{(l)} $$

I know these expressions are equal to each other because after equation 17-100 the book notes that the quantities inside the parentheses with subscripts (e) and (l) are scalars and so can be placed anywhere in the expression. But my question is that equation 17-100 is *before rearrangement of the terms*, not after rearrangement.

Comment: They did rearrange the terms, you'll note that the u's and v's have switched places (you seem to have missed a v in your transcription as it says $\bar{s}$ and not $\bar{v}_s$.).

Comment: Maybe if you make it more clear which part you think isn't following the matrix rule you've specified.

Comment: Thanks @Triatticus! Typo about missing v fixed.

Comment: And added explanation of $A^*, B^*, C^*$ to make address your second comment about which part I am confused about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from the book seems correct. M is a scalar composed by three terms (I won't write explicitly the $p_i$ dependencies in the spinors for the ease of the reading):

- $\bar{u}_{s_2^\prime}\gamma_\alpha v_{s_1^\prime} \equiv z_1$
- $\frac{ie^2}{\left(p_1+p_2\right)^2} \equiv z_2$
- $\bar{u}_{s_1^\prime}\gamma^\alpha u_{s_2^\prime} \equiv z_3$

Calling each **scalar**, $z_i$, we can say:

$$ M = z_1z_2z_3 \implies M^*=z_1^*z_2^*z_3^*$$

The term $z_2$ is pretty easy to conjugate (it is a purely imaginary number):

$$z_2^*=-z_2$$

Now, the term $z_2$ for example, we have to used the property that you mentioned, $\left(ABC\right)^\dagger=C^\dagger B^\dagger A ^\dagger$:

$$z_1^*= \left(v_{s_1^\prime}\right)^\dagger\left(\gamma_\alpha\right)^\dagger \left( \bar{u}_{s_2^\prime}\right)^\dagger$$
Using the properties of the $\gamma$ matrices:

$$\left(\gamma^\mu\right)^\dagger=\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$$
$$\left(\gamma^0\right)^\dagger=\gamma^0$$

We can simplify to:

$$z_1^*=\left[\left(v_{s_1^\prime}\right)^\dagger\gamma_0\right]\gamma_\alpha\gamma_0 \left[u_{s_2^\prime}^\dagger \gamma_0\right]^\dagger$$

And finnaly:

$$z_1^*=\left[\bar{v}_{s_1^\prime}\right]\gamma_\alpha\gamma_0 \gamma_0\left[u_{s_2^\prime}\right]$$

Using that $\gamma_0^2=1$ we obtain the expression from the book:

$$z_1^*=\left[\bar{v}_{s_1^\prime}\right]\gamma_\alpha\left[u_{s_2^\prime}\right]$$

You can now workout the same strategy for the $z_3$ term and obtain exactly the expression from the book.